# LibreOffice toolbar icons went blank after application hanged

Tags: libreoffice, 17.10

I open an excel file containing a macro in LibreOffice cal, then my LibreOffice was hanged for while. So, I decide to force end its process by issued command `ps aux | grep libreoffice`, `kill 3401 -f` to force close application.

However, on next open, my LibreOffice toolbar icons were all blank like this:

[image]

As I use office document often, it makes me have a hard time formatting my document.

Really much appreciate for any help please. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Open the "LibreOffice" application (*not* Writer or Calc or any other individual application).
2. Go to *Tools > Options > View* (or press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f12</kbd> and then select *View*).
3. Select a different option (for example *Breeze*) in the box next to "*Icon style:*" and click on *OK*.

[image]

Then Open LibreOffice Writer (or Calc etc.) and see if the icons are visible now. If not, try selecting another "*Icon style*" following the steps above.

Comment: ah it working great. Thanks very much for your help  :)